# Does System.Net.Http.HttpClient suffer from HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering?

Tags: .net, httpclient, out-of-memory

I've been trying to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to POST a larger file (+1GB) but it throws a `SystemOutOfMemory` exception:

```
at System.Net.ScatterGatherBuffers.AllocateMemoryChunk(Int32 newSize)
at System.Net.ScatterGatherBuffers..ctor(Int64 totalSize)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.EnableWriteBuffering()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetRequestSubmitDone(ConnectStream submitStream)
at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean onSubmitThread, HttpWebRequest request, TriState needReConnect)
at System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean forcedsubmit)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, String connName)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingRequestStream(RequestState state)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.PrepareAndStartContentUpload(RequestState state)
```

Apparently, a similar problem occurs for `HttpWebRequest` as discussed here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573.

Is there any way to set `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` of the underlying web request to `false`? I can't find any.

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to save time of others interested, I'm answering my own question.

After a few tests the exception seems to be down to the same issue with `HttpWebRequest` as discussed in the question. I use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi version 4.0.20710.0.

Below are two equivalent pieces of code; the former fails on large files, whereas the latter works fine.

BTW, despite the issue overall benefits of the `HttpClient` become really apparent :-)

---

### using `HttpClient`

```
var clientRef = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(
    new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MyUsername, MyPassword)
    });
clientRef.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverAddress);
clientRef.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
clientRef.PostAsync(
    MyFavoriteURL,
    new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(inputStream)).ContinueWith(
        requestTask =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning).Wait();
```

---

### using `HttpWebRequest`

```
// Preauthenticate
var req  = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(MyFavoriteURL);
req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MyUsername, MyPassword);
req.Method = "POST";
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Timeout = 10000;
using (var resp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
     if (resp.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted && resp.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         throw new Exception("Authentication error");
     }
}

// Upload
req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(MyFavoriteURL);
req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MyUsername, MyPassword);
req.Method = "POST";
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Timeout = 1200000;
req.ContentLength = inputStream.Length;
req.ContentType = "application/binary";
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
req.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    inputStream.CopyTo(reqStream);
}

using (var resp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    if (resp.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted && resp.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error uploading document");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `ExpectContinue` set to `false`? What is the purpose of the `ContinueWith` block after the `PostAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue for large file upload. Adding my findings so that it will help someone.

HttpClient determine whether to do buffering based on the following conditions,

```
if( HttpRequestMessage.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked == true ||     HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength != null )
{
  //do streamed upload
}else
{
  //do buffered upload.
}
```

I have used the PushedStreamContent as HttpRequestMessage.Content because my server accepts at max 150 MB per request. Once I set the TransferEncodingChunked to True the memory spike is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a duplicate header, you can remove the former

```
req.Headers.Add("ExpectContinue", "false");
...
req.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
```

Comment: I removed unneeded line. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Helped me send a large file without buffering through a 'relay controller'.
The scenario that I got to work was:
Client web app(spa, etc) -> RelayController -> Final content controller storing the http data stream

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
  RequestUri = new Uri("https://someurl/api/upload"),
  Method = HttpMethod.Post,
};
request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
request.Content = new StreamContent(Request.Body);

await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Had spent a lot of time on getting it to work, got the lead from Prakash P, who had the httpclient streaming vs buffering logic posted.