# .Net HTTP POST FileStream / without using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, post, windows-phone

`HttpClient.PostAsync(uri, StreamContent)` seems to use a `MemoryStream` behind the scenes even if I create `StreamContent` using a `FileStream`. Is there any way to `HTTP POST` a `FileStream` from .Net without using a `MemoryStream`? Can I modify `MS.Internal.InternalWebRequestStream.Write` (see stack trace below) to not use a `MemoryStream`?

Stack trace:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 

   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value) 
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value) 
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
   at MS.Internal.InternalWebRequestStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
   at System.IO.Stream.<BeginWriteInternal>b__11(Object param0) 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() 
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to post your code..

Comment: @EZI I've added some code. It looks like `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` might be what I'm after.

Comment: You don't `Dispose` HttpClient. Put all of it into *using* block. Do you also dispose the FileStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use an `HttpWebRequest` and set `AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037249/does-system-net-http-httpclient-suffer-from-httpwebrequest-allowwritestreambuffe).